# Remove for loop in python pandas find and replace text

Tags: python, performance, pandas, for-loop, vectorization

I have 2 pandas dataframes. I want to do a find and replace between 2 dataframes. In the `df_find` dataframe, in the current_title column, i want to search in every row for any occurrence of values from '`keywrod`' column in the `df_replace` dataframe and if found replace it with corresponding value from '`keywordlength`' column.

I have been able to get rid of the loop for `df_find` dataframe since i need to iterate over every row in this dataframe by using `str.replace` which is a vectorized form of `replace` function.

Performance matters in my case, as both the dataframes run into GB's. So, i want to get rid of the loop for `df_replace` here and use any other efficient way of iterating through all rows of `df_replace` dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df_find = pd.read_csv("input_find.csv")
df_replace = pd.read_csv("input_replace.csv")

#replace
for i,j in zip(df_replace.keyword,df_replace.keywordLength):
    df_find.current_title=df_find.current_title.str.replace(i,j,case=False)
```

df_replace
This dataframe has the data we need for find and replace

```
keyword       keywordLength
IT Manager    ##10##
Sales Manager ##13##
IT Analyst    ##12##
Store Manager ##13##
```

df_find is where we need to do the transformation.

Before executing find and replace code:

```
current_title
I have been working here as a store manager since after I passed from college
I am sales manager and primarily work in the ASEAN region. My primary rolw is to bring new customers.
I initially joined as a IT analyst and because of my sheer drive and dedication, I was promoted to IT manager position within 3 years
```

After executing find and replace through above code

```
current_title
I have been working here as a ##13## since after I passed from college
I am ##13## and primarily work in the ASEAN region. My primary rolw is to bring new customers.
I initially joined as a ##12## and because of my sheer drive and dedication, I was promoted to ##10## position within 3 years
```

I will be ever grateful! Thanks

Comment: Would the matched values be complete matches, or maybe only substring matches?  And what if there are multiple matches? Do you just take the first match?

Comment: All matches are replaced. It's complete match.

Comment: Look into regular expressions and `re.sub`. You could read the file as text, replace what you want to replace with regex and then open it as a csv.

Comment: str.replace is vectorized implementation of re-sub. It performs the operation on the entire column instead of a single row.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to do a relatively simple merge on your data sets (with a few other lines) and get the desired result.

Not having your data sets, I just made up my own.  The following code could probably be a bit more elegant, but it gets you where you need to be in four lines, and most importantly - no looping:

**Setup:**

```
df_find = pd.DataFrame({
            'current_title':['a','a','b','c','b','c','b','a'],
            'other':['this','is','just','a','bunch','of','random','words']
        })

df_replace = pd.DataFrame({'keyword':['a','c'], 'keywordlength':['x','z']})
```

**Code:**

```
# This line is to simply re-sort at the end of the code.  Someone with more experience can probably bypass this step.
df_find['idx'] = df_find.index

# Merge together the two data sets based on matching the "current_title" and the "keyword"
dfx = df_find.merge(df_replace, left_on = 'current_title', right_on = 'keyword', how = 'outer').drop('keyword', 1)

# Now, copy the non-null "keywordlength" values to "current_title"
dfx.loc[dfx['keywordlength'].notnull(), 'current_title'] = dfx.loc[dfx['keywordlength'].notnull(), 'keywordlength']

# Clean up by dropping the unnecessary columns and resort based on the first line above.
df_find = dfx.sort_values('idx').drop(['keywordlength','idx'], 1)
```

**Output:**

```
  current_title   other
0             x    this
1             x      is
3             b    just
6             z       a
4             b   bunch
7             z      of
5             b  random
2             x   words
```

Comment: This isn't what i am looking for. I added an example of before and after to make it more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, that's exactly why I asked if they were complete matches or substring matches... Regardless, this highlights the importance of posting data sets.

Comment: Its a complete match. we are replacing entire keyword with  keywordLength. code in the for loop does that. Not sure if you meant something else by 'complete match' but i went by its literal meaning.

Comment: would you have any help for me?